How do I install selenium to test a website navigation on Windows?
I want to learn to use selenium using python, I created a website hosted on Xampp, but I want to test the navigation using selenium, I don't know how to get started. I have created a workspace in VSC, added the Xampp folder with the website. I downloaded a chromedriver as well and added it to the path on system variables.  but when I tried to use pip install selenium on VSC terminal this is what I got.
PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\xampp> pip install selenium
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python313\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python313\Scripts\pip.exe" install selenium': The system cannot find the file specified.

PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\xampp> 

I tried to use pip install selenium on VSC terminal this is what I got.
PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\xampp> pip install selenium
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python313\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python313\Scripts\pip.exe" install selenium': The system cannot find the file specified.

PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\xampp> 


i believe this error is from pip not being linked properly; or python PATH not set correctly. Try to add the path to Python's installation directory C:\Program Files\Python313. You can also try homebrew to install these!

Steps to check and fix the issue:

Verify that python is installed using "python --version".
Verify that pip is installed using "python -m pip --version".
Check PATH Environment variable. Right-click on "This PC" or "My computer" and select properties. click on "Advanced system settings" and then click on "Environment Variables".
Under the "System variables" find path and then click on edit.
Add the location of python and python\scripts. (See picture 1).
picture 1
Install selenium using "pip install selenium".

If you get the error again, try to reinstall python and pip. Make sure you set the path variable correctly. To reinstall python and pip, please read this doc
